check whether new array contains the special character using hashmap
New to JavaScript Programming. So I will make this short for you to read so you dont waste your time.
Trying to get a check to work for a password generator.
const chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,"!", "@", "#", "$", "%" ]
const specialChars = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%"]
const nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const genEl = document.getElementById("generate-el")
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
genEl.addEventListener("click", generate);
let pass = [];

let randSpecialChars = specialChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * specialChars.length)]
let randNums = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length)]

const table ={};
table['randSpecialChars'] = randSpecialChars;
table['randNums'] = randNums;

function generate(){
    for(let i=0; i<10 && i<chars.length; i++){
        pass[i] = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        inputEl.value = pass.join('');
};

    for(let i=0; i<pass.length; i++){
        if(specialChars.includes(pass[i])){
            return
        }
        else if(nums.includes(pass[i])){
            return
        }
        else{
            if(pass.includes(table['randSpecialChars'])=== false){
            pass.pop();
            pass.push(table['randSpecialChars'])}
            else if(pass.includes(table['randNums']==false)){
            pass.pop();
            pass.push(table['randSpecialChars'])
            }
            
        }
    }
};


My logic:
If the generated password does not contain the special character pop the last element from the array and then push the random Special Character from the hashmap.
Same for the randNum it gets a random number from the array stores it in a variable, the number is then stored in the hashmap AS the value.
Any help and improvement would be appreciated. Thanks !

Can you explain what the issue is? Do you have an error? Is something not working like you expected? Is something difficult to implement? So, if you kindly explain what the exact problem is, then I would be happy to help.

Hi! Sorry for not explaining appropriately. What I am trying to do is set a check for special characters, numbers, and capital characters. For instance, if the password that was generated does not contain any special characters, capital alphabets or numbers the pass array's last element is popped and replaced with a random character,number or the capital letter (I havent implemented the logic for the capital alphabet either). TLDR ; I need help with a better way to check whether the the generated password contains special character, number or capital Alphabet.

Also this is me trying to implement all the concepts I have learned, hence why it it looks awful lol. Thanks in Advance

Maybe this regex will work for you:

/[ `!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"\|,.<>/?~]/



function checkForSpecialChars(password) {
    return /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/.test(password);
}
<input type="text" oninput="checkForSpecialChars(this.value) ? console.log('yup') : console.log('nope')">



Now, if you have a text and it contains a regex, you might want to replace a character in it, but why the last one? Why not any of it?


let specialCharacter = "."; //use yours instead, this is just a test

let context = document.getElementById("foo");

let value = foo.value;

let position = Math.random() * value.length;

foo.value = value.substring(0, position - 1) + specialCharacter + value.substring(position);
<input type="text" value="123456789" id="foo">



Combine the two and your problem will be solved.

Thanks alot! Took me a while to figure out how to implement the regular Expressions with if statements but it works. I also wanted to ask, is using conditional statements a with regular expressions is a valid approach or not?

@wizerdd basically the feature you want is to have something that generates a valid password. A valid password according to your standards contains a special character at least. So, you generate a password and if it does not contain at least a special character, then you add one at a certain place. This all sounds reasonable to me, but it also makes sense to randomize the special character from a larger array, like ['.', ',', ';', ':'] and a bunch of other special characters I was too lazy to type in. So, if your initial password does not contain a spec char, then you randomize one and

@wizerdd you also randomize its location. Assuming that specialChars is an array (similar to the one in my previous comment), you can get a random special character from it via something like specialChars[parseInt(Math.random() * specialChars.length)].

Thank you! I learned something from all of this.

@wizerdd happy to help! If this answer helped you figure out the solution, then you might consider marking it as the correct answer.
